# ASP.Net Core WebAPI POST Request always returns "bad request"

Tags: asp.net-core, post, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a very basic WebAPI project set up with bare-bones request handlers

```
 [HttpPost]
 public void Post([FromBody] string value)
 {
 }
```

And whenever I try to make any kind of POST request from my front-end (no matter what the shape of the POST request is) I get this same response:

> {"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"Bad Request","status":400,"traceId":"|67f1b99e-44f1042c5e8d50b2."}

I'm attempting to make the request from a front-end razor page in Orchard Core CMS, but I'm not sure if that's even relevant, since I get the same non-response from Postman as well. The request doesn't even make it to my Post() method in the controller.

Could anyone enlighten me as to what the POST request should look like? (without jquery preferably)

Comment: Just to double check, when you're running the post you're including a string "value" in the body, right?

Comment: This is the current way I'm sending the request, but the result is the same if I remove the "value" argument from Post() and send an empty request
<form method="post" action="/api/comments">
        <input name="value" id="value" value="comment" style="resize:none;"></input>
        <input type="submit" />
 </form>

Comment: Ah Razor. I missed that. Have to forgive me as I haven't used it in some time. Believe the action refers to a controller/action in the MVC framework, and not a route like a JS frontend app. Likely that distinction has something to do with it. Best bet unless someone else comes along would likely be to check the asp.net core mvc docs on posting forms.